# textview Automatic scroll in mintues

Tags: ios, textview

I have an app for iOS that display some files in a tableview which the filetype is "txt".I want to make a E-book app，it  can  display the txt file in a textview,and count the words,input how many words /min user want to read ,the textview begin to scroll and finish scroll in some minute
Hope for you help,Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UITextView or a UIWebView, use a repeating NSTimer, calculate the ratio of how much of the minute is completed, and use it to set the contentOffset of the view.

**Updated with more detail:**

This is approximate and untested.  It will scroll it in one minute.  To create a timer,

```
NSTimer* timer = [scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateScroll) repeats:YES];
startingTime = NSDate.date.timeIntervalSinceNow; //store in object
```

Update the view.  I think this will scroll the text off the screen.

```
-(void)updateScroll
{
    double minutesSinceStart = (NSDate.date.timeIntervalSinceNow - startingTime) / 60.0;
    myTextView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(minutesSinceStart * myTextView.contentSize.height, 0);
}
```

Comment: Can you detailed More description?example which function I will use,or a example code.Thank for you help

Comment: I'll edit to add some, but then you need to at least give it a shot and code.  Then you'll have something to post for us to continue helping you.

Comment: I use these code can make the textview begin to scroll,but the textview scroll from down to top,Iwant it from top to down,I hope you can help me find which code have problem.

Comment: I use these code can make the textview begin to scroll,but the textview scroll from down to top,Iwant it from top to down,I hope you can help me find which code have problem.Thank you for your help
-(IBAction)startbutton:(id)sender{
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateScroll) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    self.startingTime = [NSDate date];
}
-(void)updateScroll
{
    double noSeconds = (double) [self.startingTime timeIntervalSinceNow] /60;
    frtextview.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,noSeconds * frtextview.contentSize.height);
}

Comment: For the content offset, try frtextview.contentSize.height - noSeconds * frtextview.contentSize.height to reverse the scroll.